# How do I get the "Massive Blow" achievement?

Tags: achievements, diablo-iii

What's the most reliable way to achieve "Massive Blow"?

[image: Massive Blow: Kill 20 Monsters in one hit]

Comment: Try the Jar of Souls!

Comment: Why would you necro this, Brythan?

Comment: @Vac this is *not a forum*, "necro-ing" things is *perfectly acceptable*, you can even get a [bronze](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/198/revival) or [silver](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge for it!  Granted, for minor edits it's not the best use, but it's still fine.

Answer (score 9):

This can be easily achieved in the cathedral, with the wizard.

**After you get to level 10+** go around the cathedral (whichever level) and gather up a few monsters.

After that, **use frost nova to stun them and deal some damage**, and then **use wave of force to kill them all with one blast.**

This is the way i did it and everything went incredibly smoothly.

Hope i could help, cheers :)

Comment: Secondary concern: how do you prevent your friends from joining the game and adding HP to everything?

Comment: On the settings menu it says open beta to public. You need to have this option disabled. Its simple, just restart the game and tell your friends not to join. Only friends will be allowed to join (from character selection screen) but other random players wont.

Comment: @NickT IN addition to what thekrazypig said, when you click on Start Game/Resume Game on your character's menu, it creates a game with public access turn off by default... At least it is for me. Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to explicitly deny access to friends as well as public players. There might implement one later though. You'll never know.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to find the Jar of Souls event and wait for lots of things to spawn.

Then:

- As a Witch Doctor, try using Grasp of the Dead.
- As a Barbarian, try using Hammer of the Ancients.
- As a Monk, try Crippling Wave.
- As a Demon Hunter, try using Rapid Fire.
- As a Wizard, the Frost Nova + Wave of Force combo.

Answer (score 1):

Got it by accident using Disintegrating Ray on the mobs at the very start of Act 4. There's a billion of them and they have no life. Wait till then imo.

Comment: Just saw this - as a wizard in Iskatu fight, try Archon its great fun (the tiny mobs mean a **huge** extension to archon time)

Comment: no, there's only about 350 of them, not billion